# c++ Schwarz counter with thread_local

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, static-order-fiasco

Can I use [Schwarz counter (aka Nifty counter)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter) idiom, with `thread_local`? (Assuming I replace all `static` with `thread_local`)

I need this (helper for java jni threads):

```
class ThisThread{
    JNIEnv* jni_env{nullptr};
public:
    JNIEnv* getEnv(){
        if (!jni_env){
            // Attach thread
            java_vm->GetEnv((void**)&jni_env, JNI_VERSION);
            java_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni_env, NULL);
        }

        return jni_env;
    }

    ~ThisThread(){
        if (!jni_env) return;
        // Deattach thread
        java_vm->DetachCurrentThread();
    }
};

static thread_local ThisThread this_thread;
```

To be constructed first, and destructed last in each thread.
I may call `this_thread->getEnv()` from destructor/constructor of other static or thread_local object.

**UPDATE**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30200992 - here, standard says that thread_local destructors called BEFORE static, and I need this one to be after.

Comment: You will need the reference to ThisThread to be thread_local also.

Comment: @RichardHodges what do you mean?

Comment: sec, will knock up a demo

Comment: Here is a working wrapper: http://w01fe.com/blog/2009/05/c-callbacks-into-java-via-jni-made-easyier/

Comment: @AlexCohn It is the same as in question. And have the same problem - it destructor may be called before other thread_local and static destructors. I think I almost have universal solution for this, I will post answer with this. Richard Hodges thread_local nifty counter is not enough alone, because static destructors too may try access env (and thread_local destructed before statics + destruction may occur not on main thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208350/1559666).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to implement the schwartz counter as normal, but implement the `ThisThread` class in terms of a `thread_local` static `Impl`.

Complete example with outputs:

```
// header file
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::mutex emit_mutex;

template<class...Ts>
void emit(Ts&&...ts)
{
    auto action = [](auto&&x) { std::cout << x; };
    auto lock = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(emit_mutex);

    using expand = int[];
    expand{ 0,
        (action(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), 0)...
    };
}


struct ThisThread
{
    struct Impl
    {
        Impl()
        {
            emit("ThisThread created on thread ", std::this_thread::get_id(), '\n');
        }
        ~Impl()
        {
            emit("ThisThread destroyed on thread ", std::this_thread::get_id(), '\n');
        }
        void foo() 
        { 
            emit("foo on thread ", std::this_thread::get_id(), '\n');
        }
    };

    decltype(auto) foo() { return get_impl().foo(); }

private:
    static Impl& get_impl() { return impl_; }
    static thread_local Impl impl_;
};

struct ThisThreadInit
{

    ThisThreadInit();
    ~ThisThreadInit();

    static int initialised;
};

extern ThisThread& thisThread;
static ThisThreadInit thisThreadInit;



// cppfile

static std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(ThisThread), alignof(ThisThread)> storage;
ThisThread& thisThread = *reinterpret_cast<ThisThread*>(std::addressof(storage));
int ThisThreadInit::initialised;
thread_local ThisThread::Impl ThisThread::impl_;

ThisThreadInit::ThisThreadInit()
{
    if (0 == initialised++)
    {
        new (std::addressof(storage)) ThisThread ();    
    }
}

ThisThreadInit::~ThisThreadInit()
{
    if (0 == --initialised)
    {
        thisThread.~ThisThread();
    }
}


// now use the object

#include <thread>

int main()
{
    thisThread.foo();

    auto t = std::thread([]{ thisThread.foo(); });
    t.join();
}
```

example output:

```
ThisThread created on thread 140475785611072
foo on thread 140475785611072
ThisThread created on thread 140475768067840
foo on thread 140475768067840
ThisThread destroyed on thread 140475768067840
ThisThread destroyed on thread 140475785611072
```

Comment: @tower120 why do you think it's not working? I see constructors and destructors being called as expected.

Comment: Sorry it seems due to mingw-w64 bug, or some other malfunction in my toolchain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226542/c-why-static-thread-local-object-constructed-twice . I tried with VS 2017, and it seem to work as expected in that test. But... Something still confusing me - we does not actually count thread_locals...

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer how to make Schwarz counter for `thread_local static` 's *(so I don't accept this as answer)*. But in the end, I came up with this platform-dependent(Linux/Android) solution.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cassert>
#include "JavaVM.h"

namespace jni_interface{

    class ThisThread{
        inline static thread_local pthread_key_t p_key;

        static void pthread_dstr(void *arg){
            if (!jni_env) return;
            java_vm->DetachCurrentThread();
            jni_env = nullptr;

            pthread_setspecific(p_key, NULL);
            pthread_key_delete(p_key);
        }

        static void register_dstr(void *arg){
            {
                const int res = pthread_key_create(&p_key, pthread_dstr);
                assert(res != EAGAIN);
                assert(res != ENOMEM);
                assert(res == 0);
            }
            {
                const int res = pthread_setspecific(p_key, arg);
                assert(res == 0);
            }
        }

        inline static thread_local JNIEnv* jni_env{nullptr};
    public:
        JNIEnv* getEnv(){
            if (!jni_env){
                assert(java_vm);
                java_vm->GetEnv((void**)&jni_env, JNI_VERSION);
                java_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&jni_env, NULL);       // safe to call in main thread

                register_dstr(jni_env);
            }

            return jni_env;
        }
    };

    static thread_local ThisThread this_thread;
}
```

Even if by some reason, `pthread_dstr` will be called before C++'s static thread_locals (or interleaved) [in other words `ThisThread` destroyed before last use], on next call to object (`getEnv()`) we kinda re-init/re-create it and register `pthread_dstr` for another round.

**N.B.** At total maximum we can have `PTHREAD_DESTRUCTOR_ITERATIONS` rounds, which is 4. But we always will end up on a second one, at worst case (if C++ thread_local implementation will use p_thread destructors [which will mean that OUR `pthread_dstr` may not be called last in the first round]).