# are C++ static variables always destructed on main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static

Short question:

Are C++11 static (non thread_local) variables always destructed on main thread?

Are they always destroyed on program exit only (considering we do not call manually their destructors)?

**UPDATE**

For brevity, lets assume that destructors ARE called. (we did not pull the plug, we did not kill -9)

Comment: Are you asking _if_ the C++ language spec _guarantees_ that the destructors of `static` objects will be called when the program exits?  (I don't know the answer, but I would not count on it.)

Comment: So you're wondering if the main thread is the one that calls the destructors when your program is multi-threaded? And that the destructors are *always* called at program termination, and never skipped?

Comment: @jameslarge the standard may well guarantee that destructors will be called, but I don't know the answer either.

Comment: > So you're wondering if the main thread is the one that calls the destructors when your program is multi-threaded?   - Yes. STATIC objects destructor.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration says  they're deallocated on program exit, but nothing about the destructor firing. I'd sure hope it does.

Comment: @MarkRansom, There's more than one way for a program to exit in most operating systems.  I don't see how anybody could guarantee that destructors will be called if, for example, somebody trips on the power cord and pulls it out of the wall.

Comment: @jameslarge - Seriously? I'm pretty sure the OP isn't asking about divine intervention, but rather about the normal means of termination as recognized by the C++ standard.

Comment: @jameslarge the usual way for a program to exit is for it to reach the end of the `main` function. If the question is about any other condition that must be stated explicitly.

Comment: Alright, just focus on which thread call their destructors.

Comment: @tower120 - That's the thing. Not even all legal ways to termiante (and I mean by "legal" those defined by the C++ standard) call destructors. As an example [`std::abort` doesn't](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.term#7). You are gonna need to constrain your question to how the program is exited.

Comment: Assume they ARE called. On which thread?

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you. I was just looking at `std::abort` and couldn't find  any assurances. Glad to know I'm not on crack. Unrelated, at cppreference the `std::abort` page isn't rendering correctly. Anyone know where to report this? Never mind on the last bit. Could be my end.

Comment: Under normal exit they are deallocated in reverse order to instantiation at the main program exit. This might be main thread, but I'm not seeing that an implementation can't do something bizarre.

Comment: Lets look from the other side : Under what conditions they will be called not on the main thread?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Destructors of the global objects are called by `std::exit`. That function is called by the C++ run-time when `main` returns.

It is possible to arrange for `std::exit` to be called by a thread other than that which entered `main`. E.g.:

```
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n'; }
    ~A() { std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n'; }
};

A a;

int main() {
    std::thread([]() { std::exit(0); }).join();
}
```

Outputs:

```
140599080433472
140599061243648
```

Showing that one thread called the constructor and another the destructor.

See [`std::exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) and [`std::atexit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) for more details.

Comment: Ugh. Race condition when the other thread takes longer than 60s. I'm amazed that people still think "sleep" was a thread synchronization primitive.

Comment: To add a bit of more constructive criticism, using ``join()`` instead of ``detach()`` would solve this issue. Of course the join will not succeed because ``std::exit()`` doesn't return, but this still removes any undefined behavior. IOW, any form of infinite wait that doesn't race with static storage duration d'tors is fine here.