# Why is a static thread_local object in C++ constructed twice?

Tags: c++, gcc, thread-safety, mingw-w64, thread-local-storage

This code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

struct Singl{
    Singl(Singl const&) = delete;
    Singl(Singl&&) = delete;

    inline static thread_local bool alive = true;

    Singl(){
        std::cout << "Singl() " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
    ~Singl(){
        std::cout << "~Singl() " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        alive = false;
    }
};

static auto& singl(){
    static thread_local Singl i;
    return i;
}

struct URef{
    ~URef(){
        const bool alive = singl().alive;
        std::cout << alive << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    std::thread([](){
        singl();
        static thread_local URef u;
    }).join();

    return 0;
}
```

Has the following output:

```
Singl() 2
Singl() 2
1
~Singl() 2
~Singl() 2
```

I'm compiling and running under Windows with mingw-w64 gcc7.2 POSIX threads.

Coliru has a different output:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3da415345ea6c2ee

What's this? Something wrong with my toolchain / compiler, or is that how it should be? Why do I have two thread_local objects (or constructed twice?) on the same thread?

Comment: I'd recommend running it in a debugger, putting a breakpoint in the `Singl` constructor, and looking at the stack trace each time you hit the breakppoint. That should give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Already done - have no clue... Same behavior on all mingw-w64 gcc 7.x . VS2017 have same output as in coliru.

Comment: @tower120 so what *do* the stack traces look like?

Comment: FWIW VS2015 only constructs `Singl` once.

Comment: FYI I cannot reproduce on wandbox gcc7.2 either

Comment: I ran it in LLVM 8.1 and got same answer as coliru

Comment: Second Singl constructed in ~URef(), constor itself called by mysterious TLS wrapper, __tls_init .  Then both destructors called on thread destruction.

Comment: I field the bug https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/688/ , will see what they say about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something wrong with your compiler or toolchain.

With both clang++ 8 and g++ 8.2 on Linux (Devuan ASCII to be exact), the thread-local variable is constructed just once.

Comment: Yes you're right - that was mingw fault. I had answer my own question.