# c++ thread_local destructors with pthread destructors

Tags: android, c++, linux, pthreads, thread-local-storage

I want to do some work after all C++ thread_local destructors called.
This is platform specific - Android, so I have access to `pthreads`.

The question is, when `pthread_key_create`d destructors should be called, before or after C++ `thread_local` destructors? Or they can be interleaved?

I tested On Linux Mint and pthread destructors called after C++ 's.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that thread_local is implemented in terms of pthread_key_create.

Comment: @RichardHodges I expect that too, at first... But! pthread_key_create destruction order is undefined, C++ thread_local destructors required to be in order. They can't be just pure pthread's. So, likely they can not be interleaved... Hence - they all be called or before, or after...

Comment: Actually, playing around on godbolt it seems that gcc actually uses a register to keep track of thread_specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[bionic/pthread_exit.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/bionic/pthread_exit.cpp) currently has the same order:

```
void pthread_exit(void* return_value) {
  // Call dtors for thread_local objects first.
  __cxa_thread_finalize();
  // Call the TLS destructors.
  pthread_key_clean_all();
```

However, this is not documented behavior and you should not build something relying on it.

Comment: What if I will re-register pthread destructor from pthread destructor, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237684/1559666 ? Documentation says that call order of destructors is undefined, but it says that it will go in iterations... C++ thread_local destructor can not re-register self (behavior by standard), so if we skip once, on second iteration we guarantee should execute after C++. Right?

Comment: @tower120 No, not guaranteed, if C++ thread_local is not using pthread destructors.

Answer (score 0):

`libstdc++` from GCC uses `pthread_key_create` in case the platform does not provide `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl`.  In this case, C++ destructors run somewhere in the middle of the POSIX destructors.

To my knowledge, there is no standard which requires any particular behavior here because C++ does not know about POSIX and POSIX does not know about C++, so neither standard says what happens here.  There are also some corner cases involving the resurrection of thread-local data during thread destruction which will vary among implementations.  (A typical example is a per-thread logger object which is used to log from destructors of thread-local variables.)